# NSTimer's isValid always returns YES

Tags: ios, nstimer

So I've got a timer that is **not** repetitive. Each time it fires, the method that being executed decide if to reschedule it or not according to some inner logic of my app.

This method is available from other parts of the app, so the first thing that I'm doing in the method is to check if the timer is still valid (to know if the initiator was the timer or a different entity) so in case it wasn't initiated by the timer I want to invalidate it:

```
if (self.pollingTimer.isValid) {
    [self.pollingTimer invalidate];
    self.pollingTimer = nil;
}
```

I've noticed that if the method is being called due to the timer being fired - I always receive a true value from the `isValid` property, even though when looking at the `NSTimer` documentations under the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats` method:

> repeats
>   If YES, the timer will repeatedly reschedule itself until invalidated. **If NO, the timer will be invalidated after it fires.**
>
> Discussion
>   After seconds seconds have elapsed, **the timer fires**,
>   sending the message aSelector to target.

I'm having hard time to understand when the timer is being automatically invalidated which bring me to my questions:

1. Any idea why I always get YES from isValid?
2. What is the exact definition of **the timer fires**? Is it just sending the message aSelector to target as stated in the documentation? or is it finishing the execution of the method? (which might explain what I'm experiencing)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you have other classes calling the same method as the timer action?

Comment: You appear to be doing everything correctly, however I would suggest having a dedicated timer callback method and have that method call your common method (i.e. the method you describe above, with the timing-related code removed).  That way you avoid the issue completely and you aren't doing timing-related activities in a non-timing-related method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A timer is not a real-time mechanism; it fires only when one of the run loop modes to which the timer has been added is running and able to check if the timer’s firing time has passed. Therefore, the timer does not immediately invalidate itself, but at the end of the run loop.

As a simple test, you can see:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (self.timer.isValid){
        NSLog(@"--> TIMER VALID");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"TIMER INVALID!");
    }
  });
}

- (void) timerFired {
  if (self.timer.isValid){
     NSLog(@"--> TIMER VALID");
  } else {
     NSLog(@"TIMER INVALID!");
  }
}
```

This will log `--> TIMER VALID` from the `timerFired` method and when the block from `dispatch_after` is called, you will see `TIMER INVALID!`. So, when you schedule a timer with `repeats:NO`, it **is guaranteed** to not reschedule itself but it will not invalidate immediately.

So, to answer your question:

> repeats
>
> If YES, the timer will repeatedly reschedule itself until
> invalidated. If NO, the timer will be invalidated after it fires **(but not immediately)**

Answer (score 1):

I made a test like this:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(xx) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

- (void)xx
{
if ([self.timer isValid]) {
    NSLog(@"isvalid");
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if ([self.timer isValid]) {
        NSLog(@"isvalid");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"isInvalid");
    }
});
static int i = 0;
NSLog(@"%d",i++);
}
```

and the result is:

> isvalid
>     0
>     isInvalid

thus, I guess when timer is fired,the function is execute like this:

```
void __NSFireTimer(){
id yourObj;
[yourObj performSelector:@selector(yourSelector)];
timer.isvalid = NO;
}
```

what you believe is:

```
void __NSFireTimer(){
id yourObj;
timer.isvalid = NO;
[yourObj performSelector:@selector(yourSelector)];
}
```

So, just accept it.You can put your check valid code in dispatch_asyn() ,like the test code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used my timers. First initialise it on the top as

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *refreshTimer;
```

then this two methods, to create and invalidate the timer. "Its very important to invalidate the current timer if you want to create another timer with same name" otherwise their will be two timers.

```
- (void)startTimer {

    if (_refreshTimer) {
        [self invalidateTimer];
    }
    _refreshTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0 
                                                     target:self 
                                                   selector:@selector(determineIfPartOfgroup) 
                                                   userInfo:nil 
                                                    repeats:YES];
}

- (void)invalidateTimer {

    if (_refreshTimer) {
        [_refreshTimer invalidate];
        _refreshTimer = nil;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: @user3125367 What comments are required?  The code seems to speak for itself and is straight forward.

Comment: @Droppy About how does this answer 1. and 2. in OP at least. Or why is original approach flawed (if it is). Code pretty always speaks for itself and it is pointless to just say "look i'm doing like this and like that, ya know". Removed downvote, but this is still not very useful, if relevant at all.